# Why is my line count function written in C slower than Ruby?

Tags: c, ruby, gcc

I have two implementations of a function that prints the number of lines in a given file, one written in C and the other in Ruby. For some strange reason, the Ruby version is 2x faster! Here's the code:

**linecount.c** (compiled with `gcc linecount.c -o linecount`)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  FILE *fp;
  int c;
  int count;

  fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");

  while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF) {
    if (c == '\n') {
      count++;
    }
  }

  fclose(fp);
  printf("%d\n", count);
  return 0;
}
```

**ruby_linecount.rb**

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

puts File.open(ARGV[0]).lines.count
```

These are the benchmarks:

```
time (for i in {1..100}; do ./linecount /usr/share/dict/words; done)
real    0m14.438s 
user    0m14.041s
sys     0m0.298s

time (for i in {1..100}; do ./ruby_linecount.rb /usr/share/dict/words; done)
real    0m6.910s
user    0m5.917s
sys     0m0.734s
```

Why is the C version so much slower? How can I improve the performance of the C code? Are there any compiler flags that would help?

Comment: You could start by asking `gcc` to optimize, using `-O2` or `-O3`.

Comment: There is a misconception that everything in Ruby is slow. Many of the built-ins in MRI Ruby use well-known optimal C code for solving problems such as scanning a string of bytes, hash lookups or sorting arrays. The slowness tends to occur if you manipulate lots of Ruby objects, as there is quite an overhead for method calls, object instantiation etc when anything and everything can be dynamic.

Comment: The c code is obviously worse( and has ub ). Try reading char by char in ruby and then compare.

Comment: I can't reproduce; your C code runs 6 times as fast as the Ruby on my machine.

Comment: @Wooble That's interesting, what machine/OS are you running on? I'm on  OSX, MacBook Pro with an i7

Comment: @fbonetti OS X (snow leopard) on a circa-2006 imac

Answer (score 2):

You can use compiler option `-O3` to optimize for performance. Also you may consider using [fgets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) to avoid reading the file character by character.

Comment: Added the -O3 option helped a bit, but it only shaved off a second or so. I'm down to 13.371s now.

Comment: @fbonetti try writing the code in ruby to read the file character by character and you will get the same or worse performance. As I suggest in the second part of my answer consider using fgets to read multiple chars at the same time.

Comment: Yes, changing the ruby code to read character by character definitely slows it down. I'm just confused because the Ruby `lines` enumerator must somehow calculate the number of newlines in a given file so I assumed that the underlying C implementation would do something similar to what I did.

Comment: Ruby doesn't have to calculate the lines, it just needs to read until a line-end is encountered, put the read data in an array element, then read more. C supports reading by lines via `fgets`, so Ruby would piggyback on that.

Answer (score 1):

Reading from a file is a high-latency operation.  Most likely, the speed of the C version could be increased by reading larger blocks of data from the file.

I offer two examples.

This first one uses a 16K buffer.  The buffer size might be changed to see even better performance.

**EXAMPLE 1**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define BUFSIZE (16 * 1024)

int main(int argc, char **argv)
   {
   int rCode;
   FILE *fp = NULL;
   char *buf = NULL;
   int count = 0;
   size_t bufLen;

   errno=0;
   fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
   if(NULL == fp)
      {
      rCode=errno;
      fprintf(stder, "fopen() failed.  errno:%d\n", errno);
      goto CLEANUP;
      }

   errno=0;
   buf = malloc(BUFSIZE);
   if(NULL == buf)
      {
      rCode=errno;
      fprintf(stder, "malloc() failed.  errno:%d\n", errno);
      goto CLEANUP;
      }

   bufLen = fread(buf, 1, BUFSIZE, fp);
   while(bufLen)
      {
      char *cp;

      for(cp=buf; (cp < buf + bufLen); ++cp)
         if('\n' == *cp)
            ++count;

          bufLen = fread(buf, 1, BUFSIZE, fp);
      }

   printf("%d\n", count);

CLEANUP:

   if(fp)
      fclose(fp);

   if(buf)
      free(buf);

   return(rCode);
   }
```

This next one maps the file into the process memory map (or address space).  Then, looking for new-lines is memory `search for newlines` operation.

**EXAMPLE 2**

```
#include <errno.h>    /* errno, ... */
#include <fcntl.h>    /* open(), O__RDONLY, ... */
#include <stdio.h>    /* fprintf(), stderr, printf(), ... */
#include <sys/mman.h> /* mmap(), PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, ... */
#include <sys/stat.h> /* fstat(), struct stat, ... */
#include <unistd.h>   /* close(), ... */

int main(int argc, char **argv)
   {
   int rCode=0;
   int fd = (-1);
   struct stat statBuf;
   char *fileBuf=NULL;
   char *cp;
   int   count=0;

   errno=0;
   fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
   if((-1) == fd)
      {
      rCode=errno;
      fprintf(stderr, "open() failed.  errno:%d\n", errno);
      goto CLEANUP;
      }

   errno=0;
   if((-1) == fstat(fd, &statBuf))
      {
      rCode=errno;
      fprintf(stderr, "fstat() failed.  errno:%d\n", errno);
      goto CLEANUP;
      }

   errno=0;
   fileBuf = mmap(
         NULL,            /* preferred start address, normally NULL (system chooses) */
         statBuf.st_size, /* length of the mapped region */
         PROT_READ,       /* memory protection */
         MAP_SHARED,      /* private/shared */
         fd,              /* fd of mapped file */
         0                /* file offset (should be a multiples of a page) */
         );
   if((void *)(-1) == fileBuf)
      {
      rCode=errno;
      fprintf(stderr, "mmap() failed.  errno:%d\n", errno);
      goto CLEANUP;
      }

   for(cp=fileBuf; cp < fileBuf + statBuf.st_size; ++cp)
      if('\n' == *cp)
         ++count;

  printf("%d\n", count);

CLEANUP:

   if(fileBuf)
      munmap(fileBuf, statBuf.st_size);

   if((-1) != fd)
      close(fd);

   return(rCode);
   }
```

**EDIT**

I agree with the `Neil Slater's` comment.  While the examples above should improve the speed of the operation (compared to the example in the question code); Perhaps Ruby will be just a fast.

Comment: Reading character by character is slow in any language, including C. Reading using blocks, as you mention, is faster, though, the blocks should be reasonable size, match the sizes the I/O subsystems likes, be on even byte boundaries, etc., all the tricks used to speed up memory movement.

Answer (score 0):

Using your code on a MacBook Pro shows wrong results from the C version. I'd suggest changing the `while` loop to this:

```
 while ( (c=fgetc(fp)) != EOF )
```

using `fgetc` instead of `getc`. Moreover you can optimize the compiler with the `-O3` flag as previously suggested.

For the ruby code, it's better to use `each_line` instead of `lines` (it's a deprecated alias).

Depending on the ruby version you are using, you can get different results. On my machine, ruby is about 50 times slower than the corresponding C code.

Comment: That's odd - I'm on a MacBook Pro as well. I'll see if fgetc helps. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: The issue with the C code is reading by characters instead of lines or in blocks. Change to larger chunks and it'll easily keep up with Ruby.

Comment: @marzapower: Why do you think using `fgetc` is better than `getc`? According to Posix, "The getc() function shall be equivalent to fgetc, except that if it is implemented as a macro it may evaluate stream more than once, so the argument should never be an expression with side-effects." So if anything, `getc` should be slightly faster, but I don't believe it is implemented as a macro on Mac OS X either (it certainly isn't with glibc).

Comment: Using `getc` counts all the file characters, using `fgetc` counts just the lines. Don't know why, but the output is completely different.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do should be heavily IO-bound. In other words, most of the time is spent reading the file rather than doing actual computation. You should try to use another way of reading your file in your C version, and maybe have a look at what Ruby is using.

I'm guessing `mmap` could give you better performance that `getc`.

Also, be careful about the order in which you benchmark programs. The file will likely be in memory cache after the first run of one of the programs, making the other one faster. You should run each program multiple times in order to get more accurate timings.

Comment: How is the first sentence correct if fopen buffers the file?

Comment: How does `mmap` avoid I/O? Or, in general, what way can you read a file which doesn't do I/O?